# Missing values from JMeter results file when run remotely

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When running a test which makes use of the of the Jmeter-Plugins listener Response Times vs Threads or Active Threads Over Time remote running of the test plan produces a results file which contains missing results used to plot the actual graph, however when run locally all results are returned. E.g. when using the Response Times vs Threads:

Example of a local result:
    1383659591841,59,Example 1,200,OK,Example 1 1-579,text,true,183,22,22,59

Example of a remote result:
    1383659859149,43,Example 1,200,OK,Example 1 1-575,text,true,183,43

Note the last two fields are missing

Answer (score 0):

I would check the script definition of the two server: maybe some configuration for the "Write results to file" controller has been changed.

Take the local jmx service and copy it to the remote server.

Also, look for differences in the "# Results file configuration" section of jmeter.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that on all of the slave/remote servers the jmeter.properties file within $JMETER_HOME/bin has the following setting

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
```

By default this is set to false (and commented out)

For more informtation:

[JMeter Plugins Installation](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/)